# 3rd party library (xlwings) import fails when running bash script from pycharm on windows

Tags: python, windows, bash, pycharm, xlwings

*Python script containing xlwings pack via command prompt: error message*

So I wrote some code containing the xlwings package and created a bash file to run the code.
The issue I am facing is that when run the bash file I am getting the fallowing error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLXyA.png)

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwings'
```

Anyone have nay idea how this can be resolved?
Also, if anyone has a good idea other than bash file to run python script directly from your desktop, I would love to know.

I am running using Pycharm and windows 10.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you downloading/installing `xlwings`?  How are you running the bash script?  From the terminal inside pycharm?  I have edited the question so that hopefully somebody who can point you in the right direction for understanding venv and pip on windows will notice

Comment: the short answer is probably `pip install xlwings` but I'll let somebody who uses python and windows figure out how that answer fits into your system and question